# RDC stops working after a period of time

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop, vpn

I have a workstation with RDC configured for the employee. When they leave at the end of their day they lock the pc (<kbd>windows key</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd>). They go home connect to our VPN and log back in. Everything works fine. The following morning they will attempt to log in before they return to the office. The computer does not respond to the RDC request. I've found that it becomes completely inactive to any ICMP requests. Once the user reboots the computer everything works fine again. I'm going to turn off RDC, reboot, turn RDC back on and reboot again to see if it fixes the problem. Until then does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: What do they do from home at night? Does it work if they just connect, disconnect, and reconnect from home (without doing anything else)?

Comment: it works fine if they connect once then disconnect then within a short period reconnect. It seems like a long period of time causes the computer to lock everything out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out the Ethernet diag utility was the problem. Uninstalled it and things have worked fine for 2 days now.